# Hosting: Parse.com with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, parse-platform

I am trying to make an scalable app using Parse with a search function provided by ElasticSearch.

It seems like I will have to host my own ElasticSearch server which connects to Parse via the ES MongoDB river.

Is this true?  Or will Parse handle hosting ES.

I am new to both these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same question. Googling `site:parse.com elasticsearch` currently only returns 2 results neither of which actually give us an answer. Exploring Parse's [discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/parse-developers/elasticsearch|sort:date) doesn't provide much help either - the four posts even slightly related to elasticsearch hint at the possibility that Parse wont host ES.

So the answer is... drum roll... maybe :(